# If n=(sin^2(2x))/4cos^2(x))+1/(sec^2(x)) and x=2.01307, find 2013n^2013

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, contest-math

If $n=\dfrac{sin^2(2x)}{4cos^2(x)+\dfrac{1}{sec^2(x)}}$ and $x=2.01307$,
find 2013n^2013

Your edits are wrong!  These are two separate fractions not together!anymore!

Comment: Calvin, done! Sorry man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Use the identity $\sin(2x)=2\sin x\cos x$.